# How to deal with the EmptySet regex constructor in coq proofs (and other general coq questions)?

Tags: regex, coq, theorem-proving

I'm trying to figure out how to approach the `app_ne` problem in **SF**.  My thinking is to induct over the first regular expression, as it will allow us to satisfy the first disjunct, whereas all the other regular expression forms will allow one to prove the existential right disjunct.

(i)  Is this a correct approach to the problem?
(ii) If so, how does one deal with the empty set case?  This got me right away.
(iii) Is there any way admit a single part of a proof and then come back to it later (since this easy case is throwing me off and I would like to work through some of the other cases..)

```
Lemma app_ne : forall (a : ascii) s re0 re1,
    a :: s =~ (App re0 re1) <->
    ([ ] =~ re0 /\ a :: s =~ re1) \/
    exists s0 s1, s = s0 ++ s1 /\ a :: s0 =~ re0 /\ s1 =~ re1.
Proof.
  intros.
  split.
  - intros. induction re0.
    * right. inversion H.
      (* + apply re_not_empty_correct. *)
      (* + apply MEmpty. *)
Abort.
```

Comment: One general bit of advice: if you cannot prove your lemma on paper, proving it in Coq is going to be quite painful.  In general, I've found that if I reach a subgoal and I can't explain to a person why the subgoal ought to be true (and, ideally, why this subgoal is needed to prove the lemma), then I'm not going to be able to prove my lemma.

Answer (score 0):

> My thinking is to induct over the first regular expression, as it will allow us to satisfy the first disjunct,

I don't understand that reasoning (maybe it's not what you actually meant). If you could just prove the first disjunct, then there would be no point in having a disjunction in the first place.

> whereas all the other regular expression forms will allow one to prove the existential right disjunct.

"other" than what?

> (iii) Is there any way admit a single part of a proof and then come back to it later (since this easy case is throwing me off and I would like to work through some of the other cases..)

There is the `admit.` tactic to skip the current goal and the `Admitted.` command to skip the whole proof.

---

Hint for this problem: what does the first assumption mean: `a :: s =~ (App re0 re1)` (i.e., look at what the definition of `=~` says about `App`)?

Comment: I'm saying (hypothetically) that the only case, or regex constructor, where the first disjunct will be satisfied is when re0 is in fact the EmptyStr  constructor, and in all other cases the second disjunct will follow.  Additionally, I appreciate the hint but don't understand how MApp will help because we don't know where the ++ operator should happen in s.

Comment: One way to know (a bit more) is to do case analysis on one of the operands of `++`.